# Using pch the option in plot

Tags: r, plot

I want to use basic graphs to `1:10` where the point shape alternate between a plus sign (i.e. `+`) and a triangle.

It might appear that the following code `plot(1:10, pch = c("+",2))` will work.  This is because `pch=2` corresponds to the triangle.  The code, however, yields:

[image]

This of course occurs because the `c()` function coerces the `2` to a character.  My question is, how would I pass both a string and an integer to pch?

Thanks!

Comment: I would simply do `plot(1:10, pch = c(3,2))`.

Comment: @Pascal Write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @Pascal's answer works fine if you can find a suitable `pch=` argument for your desired piece of text, you can still use arbitrary text by making several calls to `points`:

```
x <- 1:10
shapes <- list("Y",2)
plot(x,type="n")
Map(points, split(data.frame(seq_along(x), x), seq_along(shapes)), pch=shapes )
```

Or convert everything to numbers using some trickery:

```
plot(x, pch=sapply(shapes, function(x) if(is.character(x)) strtoi(charToRaw(x),16L) else x))
```

Comment: Or  `plot(1:10, pch = c(89,2))`.

Comment: @Pascal - that may be true, but just being able to type "Y" or "C" or "ü" is easier than remembering what 89 etc represents.

Comment: Maybe. I personally prefer to use [this kind of link](https://www.hesa.ac.uk/component/content/article?id=1531]) rather than running 3 lines for a base plot.

Comment: Pascal, I appreciate your practical solution.  However, I was more interested in a solution to similar to thelatemail's.  Thank you both!